# How can I factory reset an iPhone 7 without the Apple ID password?

Tags: iphone, apple-id

My daughter bought an iPhone 7 a few months ago from a friend of a friend.  We found out a few days ago that it still has someone else's Apple ID on it.

We do not have the password for this Apple account.

We would like to factory reset this phone, but we can't find a way to do it without the Apple ID password. Our last attempt was to use iTunes to put it into recovery mode, but then that failed because to restore the phone, we had to turn off "Find my iPhone" ... and we can't do that without the Apple ID password.

It seems like everything we try needs this Apple ID password at some point.

What are our options here? We no longer have any contact with the person we bought it from. And I refuse to believe there's not a way to forcibly return this phone to its original state.

I have seen advertisements for software that claims to do this. Does anyone have experience with this type of thing.